# Show datediff as seconds, milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two datetime values.

I tried `datediff(s, begin,end)` and `datediff(ms, begin,end)` however I want the difference to be returned as `seconds,milliseconds` like the following:

```
4,14
63,54
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, begin, end) / 1000, 
  DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, begin, end) % 1000
FROM ...;
```

If you absolutely must form it as a string in your SQL query (can't your presentation tier do that?), then:

```
SELECT 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),  DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, begin, end) / 1000)
  + ',' 
  + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, begin, end) % 1000), 3)
FROM ...;
```

Also I really hope you have better column names than `begin` and `end`.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you and yes my column names are different it was just for explaining my problem sorry if it confused you.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the marked answer originally produced wrong results for milliseconds 1 - 99:

Example 1 second, 27 milliseconds:

1. `DATEDIFF % 1000` will return 27
2. `CONVERT` will convert to `'27'`
3. String concatenation will build `'1' + ',' + '27'`
4. Result: `'1.27'` which means 270ms rather than 27ms

Don't forget to pad the milliseconds to three zeros:

```sql
DECLARE @start datetime2(7) = '2015-07-03 09:24:33.000'
DECLARE @end datetime2(7) = '2015-07-03 09:24:34.027'

SELECT 
    CAST (DATEDIFF(SECOND, @start, @end) AS nvarchar(3)) + N'.' +
    RIGHT('000' + CAST((DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @start, @end) % 1000) AS nvarchar(3)), 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

DATEDIFF takes only two arguments in MySQL. This works for me:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), '2019-09-09 18:52:00')
```