# Spark SQL datediff in seconds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got following code:

```
table.select(datediff(table.col("Start Time"), table.col("End Time"))).show()
```

> Date format is *2016-05-19 09:23:28 (`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`)*

Function **datediff** calculate the difference in days. But I would like to have the difference in seconds.

Comment: Check [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660647/show-datediff-as-seconds-milliseconds) post

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. If I add for example "SECONDS" oder "sec" as option to the datediff function then Eclipse shows me an error message --> Too many options for function "datediff".

Comment: `table.withColumn("date_diff", (unix_timestamp($"Start Time") - unix_timestamp($"End Time")))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`unix_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function to convert date to seconds.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//For $ notation columns // Spark 2.0
import spark.implicits._

table.withColumn("date_diff", 
   (unix_timestamp($"Start Time") - unix_timestamp($"End Time"))
).show()
```

**Edit:**(As per comment)

### UDF to covert Seconds to HH:mm:ss

```
sqlContext.udf.register("sec_to_time", (s: Long) => 
   ((s / 3600L) + ":" + (s / 60L) + ":" + (s % 60L))
)

//Use registered UDF now
table.withColumn("date_diff", 
   sec_to_time(unix_timestamp($"Start Time") - unix_timestamp($"End Time"))
).show()
```

Comment: bonus is that `unix_timestamp` also handled (for me) `varchar` input, so the `cast(... as timestamp)` step i was applying can also be subsumed in this call

Comment: @MichaelChirico: Nice catch. Yes, It has to be reversed.

Comment: (s / 60L) in the UDF will give total minute, i.e if duration is more than 1 Hr, minute part will be wrong

Comment: It should be                                        
`sqlContext.udf.register("sec_to_time", (s: Long) => 
   ((s / 3600L) + " Hr : " + ( (s % 3600L) / 60L) + " Min : " + (s % 60L) + " Sec ")
)`

Comment: @mrsrinivas can we use this `unix_timestamp` in Spark SQL?