# Date diff of ISO 8601 timestemp strings in Spark

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, timestamp

I have two datetime strings in ISO 8601 format:

> 2017-05-30T09:15:06.050298Z 
>   2017-05-30T09:15:06.054939Z

I want the time difference between above two strings using Scala in Spark environment.

Comment: have you tried anything? what do you mean by spark env, do you have a spark dataframe, and rdd?

Comment: Yes I have tried couple of options. Spark env is just an optional. I have a spark dataframe also I am checking for non dataframe operations. 

I have tried with org.joda.time.DateTime where I am able to find the difference between days only.

Comment: so what do you want the difference in then?

Comment: See for example output of my code I obtained is:
d1: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2017-05-30T09:15:06.050Z
d2: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2017-05-30T09:15:06.054Z
days: Int = 0
The difference is 0 if I try for daysBetween. But I don't want the day difference i am looking for seconds/mili seconds difference to minutes difference if any.

Comment: what spark version are you on?

Comment: spark version 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

## Nanoseconds with `LocalDateTime` of Java 8

As Spark does not support date diff above Seconds, **we need to create a UDF for Millis or Nanos**.

#### Date time related imports

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
```

#### Create UDF to date diff by nanoseconds

```
spark.udf.register("date_diff_nano", (d1: String, d2: String) => 
   val dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.n'Z'")
   val dt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(d1, dtFormatter)
   val dt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(d2, dtFormatter)

   (dt1.getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY) - dt2.getLong(ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY))
)
```

Check: [help in building DateTimeFormatter pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoGjU.png)

> By modifying `ChronoField.NANO_OF_DAY` to `ChronoField.MICRO_OF_DAY`
>   in UDF last line, we can get the date diff in micro sec also.

Now, use the UDF on any DataFrame/DataSet object.

```
import spark.implicits._ //to use $-notation on columns

// create the dataframe df
val df = ...

val resultDf = df.withColumn("date_diff", date_diff_nano($"dt1", $"dt2"))
```

Here `dt1` and `dt2` are DateTime columns in `df`

---

### Seconds diff with `unix_timestamp` of Spark SQL

Use Spark SQL predefined [`unix_timestamp(date, format)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20java.lang.String)) function to convert a date to seconds of the day (But Java `SimpleDateFormat` can support parsing  up to Milliseconds), then you can do [Date diff with Spark SQL using unix_timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41344402/1592191).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

val resultDf = df.withColumn("date_diff_sec", 
  (unix_timestamp($"dt1"), unix_timestamp($"dt2")))
```

---

### Days diff b/w two dates using `datediff`

> It accepts the datetime value of following formats
>
> - `java.sql.Timestamp`
> - `java.sql.Date`
> - String format of `'YYYY-MM-dd'`
> - String format of `'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.datediff

val resultDf = df.withColumn("date_diff_days", datediff($"dt1", $"dt2"))
```

Comment: Spark SQL unix_timestamp will ignore the millisecond part. It explicitly says so in the documentation you link to.

Comment: @sradomski: Glad to see constructive feedback. I corrected it and added additional info.

Comment: we gave up on spark millisecond handling for now and encode our timestamps as milliseconds since UTC epoch in a bigint.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in the comments you're using Joda-Time, here's an answer using it.

You said that you're calling `daysBetween`. But both dates are in the same day, so the result will always be zero. To get the difference between the dates with millisecond precision, just subtract the millis value from both `DateTime` objects:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

val s1 = "2017-05-30T09:15:06.050298Z"
val s2 = "2017-05-30T09:15:06.054939Z"

val diffInMillis = DateTime.parse(s2).getMillis() - DateTime.parse(s1).getMillis()
```

The `diffInMillis` will be `4` - the first date's fraction-of-second is `050298` and the second's is `054939`, but joda's `DateTime` has milliseconds precision, so the last 3 digits are discarded. You can check that by doing:

```
println(DateTime.parse(s1))
println(DateTime.parse(s2))
```

This will output:

> 2017-05-30T09:15:06.050Z
>   2017-05-30T09:15:06.054Z

As you can see, the difference between the dates is 4 milliseconds.

---

## New Java Date/Time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**

If you have the new `java.time` API available (JDK >= 1.8), you can also use it. If `java.time` classes are not available (JDK <= 1.7), you can try the [scala time](https://github.com/soc/scala-java-time), which is based on the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes.

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The difference is that this API has **nanoseconds** precision, so you can get the difference between the dates in nanoseconds.

```
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

val s1 = "2017-05-30T09:15:06.050298Z"
val s2 = "2017-05-30T09:15:06.054939Z"

// difference in nanoseconds
val diffInNanos = ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(Instant.parse(s1), Instant.parse(s2))
```

The value of `diffInNanos` is `4641000`. If you still want this value in milliseconds, you can divide it by 1000000, or use `ChronoUnit.MILLIS` instead of `ChronoUnit.NANOS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xml date parser, since it must adhere to ISO-8601:

```
val t1 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2017-05-30T09:15:06.050298Z")

val t2 = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2017-05-30T09:15:06.054939Z")

val diff = t1.getTimeInMillis - t2.getTimeInMillis
```